# Linux kernel 'make rpm-pkg' throws error

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I am trying to create a custom kernel rpm. So I made use of "make rpm-pkg".
Everything was going fine until it hit this error.

```
..
..
INSTALL sound/usb/line6/snd-usb-toneport.ko
INSTALL sound/usb/line6/snd-usb-variax.ko
INSTALL sound/usb/misc/snd-ua101.ko
INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko

scripts/Makefile.fwinst:43: *** mixed implicit and static pattern rules.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [_modinst_post] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.jJi4sq (%install)
RPM build errors:
Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.p88MqU (%install)
make[1]: *** [rpm-pkg] Error 1
make: *** [rpm-pkg] Error 2
```

I understand there is something wrong with Makefile declarations, but also wondering if anyone has hit this issue.

Comment: Are you using make 3.82 or 4.0? Because if you are this is probably http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=33034 .

Comment: Its 3.82. I will have to compile 4.x version then. But also keen why this wasn't a problem for anyone. I thought the kernel guys would get this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using make version 3.81 or 3.82 then this is likely the known make "bug" discussed [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=33034).

Specifically a change to what make believes is a meaningful set of targets to specify in a single list changed in an incompatible way and the kernel had been using a set of targets that became invalid.

The fix, after some back and forth between the GNU Make maintainer and some concerned other developers, was to convert the fatal error into a warning (at least temporarily).

Comment: the 4.1 also didn't help. Getting same error. I tried to workaround by separating the rules in the Makefile. But that resulted in different errors like unable to find make targets.

Comment: You split the target it was complaining about and what happened? It didn't keep complaining about that case I assume. Did it complain about some other case? 4.1 doesn't silence the warning about that mixing it just prevents it from being a fatal error. I'd be interested in seeing the error you get with 4.1 on stock makefiles and the error you get after you split the target if you wanted to pastebin/gist/etc. them.

Comment: scripts/Makefile.fwinst:43: *** mixed implicit and static pattern rules.  Stop.
Makefile:1143: recipe for target '_modinst_post' failed
make[2]: *** [_modinst_post] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IjM511 (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.IjM511 (%install)
scripts/package/Makefile:39: recipe for target 'rpm-pkg' failed
make[1]: *** [rpm-pkg] Error 1
Makefile:1235: recipe for target 'rpm-pkg' failed
make: *** [rpm-pkg] Error 2
# make --version
GNU Make 4.1

Comment: make 'INSTALL_FW_PATH=/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-4.2.0+-11.%{_arch}/lib/firmware/4.2.0+' firmware_install V=1
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.fwinst obj=firmware __fw_install
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-4.2.0+-11.%{_arch}/lib/firmware/4.2.0+/bnx2x/bnx2x-e1-6.2.9.0.fw', needed by '__fw_install'.  Stop.
Makefile:1038: recipe for target 'firmware_install' failed

Comment: Yeah, that's not at all the same problem. That's an actual build failure in the `_modinst_post` target. The package build actually failed there (and it looks like something failed to expand which led to a file with a bogus name being attempted to be built). I don't know what, specifically, was going on there. Other then that 4.1 *did* fix the "fatal error" nature of the original problem.

Comment: my recent comment above is after I change the Makefile rules. The one above it is with 4.1 which is exactly same as I get with 3.82. I do suspect something isn't right. Maybe "make rpm-pkg" doesn't work like this.

Comment: Oh... that error from make appears to be coming from *inside* the `%install` target of the rpmbuild. I'm betting you installed make 4.1 as `make-4.1` or not in the default path or similar and `rpmbuild` isn't using it. Making `make` run the 4.1 version globally (with default `PATH`) might fix that problem. The `%{_arch}` in that path is (almost certainly) the problem for the second comment's error but I'm not sure why that would have failed to expand offhand. You'd have to look at where that file path value is being generated.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to explore different options. Actually this method works on x86. I am building on arm64 where it doesn't expand the $(_arch). On x86 if I try to build for arm64, the rpm package is created for arm64, but the system expects aarch64. Basically it looks like this is broken. Maybe I should be using the old rpm building ways.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. Apparently its an issue with the UTS_MACHINE not being right for arm64. It should be aarch64 so that the packaging scripts use it right. there's also small tweak in the script that generates the rpm spec file.
So 'make' is not an issue in this case.